# Wicket is changing the requestURL

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket application which can be deployed in different environments. One of this environments is a server (lets call it S) behind a https proxy (lets call it P) so the pages on the application are accessed as

```
https://P:443/path/mountedPackage/Page?params=values
```

Everything worked fine in wicket 1.4 but with the migration to wicket 1.5, the request URL is changed to

```
http://P:443/path/mountedPackage/Page?params=values
```

(https is replaced by http) which leads to a "400 Bad Request" error. I don't know why this happens but it brokes my external links to the application.

NOTE: I had this same problem before when submitting a form and calling the method `setResponsePage(Page.class)` and I solved it by setting a different RequestTarget and manually adding "https" instead of "http" when corresponds:

on wicket 1.4

```
component.getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget
      (new RedirectRequestTarget("newURLWithPropperHttps"));
```

and on wicket 1.5

```
component.getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new 
    RedirectRequestHandler("newURLWithPropperHttps"));
```

but now I am not calling any `setResponsePage()` or similar it happens when following a normal link from outside.

Any help? It is ok to use same solution as shown, but I don't know where to implement it (I have tried on method `get()` of the `IRequestCycleProvider` but that leads me to anohter error)

Comment: I don't know the answer but it sounds like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @biziclop, probably it is, I will try to report that to see what developers say.

In the meanwhile I fixed the problem by writting my own `IRequestMapper` which acts like the default one but on method `mapHandler()` sets the protocol to https if it has to.

`final IRequestMapper o=getRootRequestMapper();
setRootRequestMapper(new IRequestMapper() {`
[...]
`@Override
public Url mapHandler(IRequestHandler r) {
  Url u=o.mapHandler(r);
  if (condition)
      u.setProtocol("https");
  return u;
}
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by writting my own `IRequestMapper` which acts like the default one but on method `mapHandler()` sets the protocol to https if it has to.

```
final IRequestMapper o=getRootRequestMapper();

setRootRequestMapper(new IRequestMapper() {
   [...] 
   @Override
   public Url mapHandler(IRequestHandler r) {
       Url u=o.mapHandler(r);
       if (condition)
          u.setProtocol("https");
       return u;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this section of the Wicket 1.5 migration guide. I hope it helps.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5#MigrationtoWicket1.5-Switchingto/fromsecuredcommunicationoverhttps